# Google Apps Script Conditional Formatting whenNumberLessThan Unable to Reference Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, conditional-formatting

I am building a spreadsheet to track expenses each month based on the budgeted value for each category. I want to highlight a cell green if the value is less than or equal to the budgeted amount and red if it is greater than the budgeted amount.

I can get it to work if I pass in the numeric value for the amount however the budget occasionally changes from month to month so I want to be able to spin up a new months spreadsheet and have it conditionally format the cell color based on a reference to the budget cell. I can do this in excel VBA but am unable to pass a reference into the whenNumberLessThan function.

```
//This errors out on trying to concatenate the row onto what is in the D column
var ruleRed = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRuleBuilder()
.whenNumberLessThan("=D".concat(row))
.setBackground("#FF0000")
.setRanges([month.getRange("C".concat(row))])
.build();

//This works with 1200 or any other numeric value
var ruleRed = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRuleBuilder()
.whenNumberLessThan(1200)
.setBackground("#FF0000")
.setRanges([month.getRange("C".concat(row))])
.build();
```

Comment: The `whenNumberLessThan` method only accepts numeric values. There is a work-around but it requires that you use the Advanced Sheet service. See [Google Sheets script conditional formatting for whenNumberLessThanOrEqualTo(string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57876122/google-sheets-script-conditional-formatting-for-whennumberlessthanorequaltostri/57877264#57877264)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view, what you are planning to do would be easier by using just Sheets as you could use Conditional Formatting by custom formula (see documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)).
But If you do need to use Google Scripts, there is 2 possible choices:

**1. Get the budget cell value on a script and use .whenNumberLessThan**

You should get the cell value and then use .whenNumberLessThan, because as mentioned this function only accepts numbers. Code would look something like this:

```
var budgetValue = SpreadsheetApp.getRange("D".concat(row)).getValue();
var ruleRed = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRuleBuilder()
.whenNumberLessThan(budgetValue)
.setBackground("#FF0000")
.setRanges([month.getRange("C".concat(row))])
.build();
```

**2. Use the .whenFormulaSatisfied**

This should use the same concept that I mentioned about Coditional with Custom Formulas

```
var ruleRed = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRuleBuilder()
.whenFormulaSatisfied("=C1<$D$".concat(row))
.setBackground("#FF0000")
.setRanges([month.getRange("C".concat(row))])
.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jonas! This worked great! I should've thought to do that. Here is what I ended up using so I could specify the row on both the C and D columns

```
var ruleRed = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
.whenFormulaSatisfied("=C".concat(row)+"<$D$".concat(row))
.setBackground("#FF0000")
.setRanges([month.getRange("C".concat(row))])
.build();
```